# Unable to connect to Informix using EntityFramework.IBM.DB2

Tags: c#, entity-framework, informix

I'm having issues connecting to an Informix database from a .Net 4.5.2 application using the **EntityFramework.IBM.DB2 (v6.0.3)** package. I keep getting the following error when I try to query the database:

> System.NotSupportedException : There is no store type corresponding to
>   the EDM type 'Edm.String' of primitive type 'String'.

The line throwing the error is:

```
var existing = db
    .MyEntities
    .FirstOrDefault(e => e.IdB == myId);
```

The entity itself:

```
public class MyEntity
{
    public long IdA { get; set; }

    public long IdB { get; set; }

    public string NameA { get; set; }

    public string NameB { get; set; }

    public ICollection<OtherEntity> OtherEntities { get; set; }
}
```

And the script used to create the table:

```
create table myentity (
  idA BIGINT not null,
  idB BIGINT not null,
  nameA NVARCHAR(200) not null,
  nameB NVARCHAR(200) not null
)
extent size 32 next size 32
lock mode page;

alter table myentity add constraint primary key 
  (idB)
  constraint pk_myentity;
```

The table config:

```
public class MyEntityConfig : EntityTypeConfiguration<MyEntity>
{
    public EventTypeConfig()
    {
        ToTable("MyEntity");
        HasKey(u => u.IdB);
        Property(u => u.IdB).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);
        Property(s => s.IdA).IsRequired();
        Property(s => s.NameA).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(200);
        Property(s => s.NameB).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(200);

        HasOptional(e => e.OtherEntities);
        HasMany(e => e.OtherEntities);
    }
}
```

When I run `testconn40` I get a Test Passed so I don't think it's an issue connecting to database. And I have another project that's working with a very similar setup so I've no idea what's wrong.

Any help or information that anyone can give on this particular error would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error was due to how .Net types were being mapped to the database types.

I had a field in one of my database tables which was type `LVARCHAR(32000)` and the corresponding field on my entity was `string`. I updated the field in the database to be `NCHAR(32000)` and also added the following to my entity config class:

```
Property(s => s.StringProp).HasMaxLength(32000).IsRequired();
```

Once I made these changes the errors disappeared.

Another strange error I came across was:

> System.NotSupportedException : There is no store type corresponding to
>   the EDM type 'Edm.Guid' of primitive type 'Guid'.

Informix doesn't seem to support the Guid type; I used `VARCHAR(36)` and mapped between Guid and string when inserting and retrieving so this error was pretty strange. It turned out to be down to how I was querying with LINQ.

This line throws the error:

```
var dbEntity = dbContext
    .MyEntities
    .FirstOrDefault(e => e.Id == myGuid.ToString());
```

Where as this works fine:

```
var id = myGuid.ToString();

var dbEntity = dbContext
    .MyEntities
    .FirstOrDefault(e => e.Id == id);
```

Basically what I've found is that you have to keep everything as simple and straightforward as possible when trying to do anything with the `EntityFramework.IBM.DB2` or you'll continue to run into cryptic errors with little or not support to be found online.

Hope this helps someone in the future.

Answer (score 0):

The EF support is only by using IBM DB2 client driver.
Since IBM DB2 client driver uses DRDA protocol, you
need to enable DRDA port with IDS server and then it should work.

The IBM DB2 Client team is more active on developerworks forum.
If you still get problem you may repost it over developerworks, the url is

https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/forum?id=11111111-0000-0000-0000-000000000467

Comment: This is enabled - I've been able to connect to the server via Entity Framework via from another application as I said in question. Also, I posted the same question in that forum when I posted this one.